# React-Native: Dispatch on submit is not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to do a basic todo list however when I dispatch an action after pressing add it doesn't dispatch .

I've taken the `dispatch(todo(todoList))`out of every function and left it in the main `ToDo` component to do multiple calls on every letter typed into the search box and I can see an update in my redux store in `Redux-dev tools` so I know my `todo` works but It won't `dispatch()` when I try to submit. Please can someone help me .

This is my code:

```
import {useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { todo } from './action/todo'

const ToDo = () => {
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState('')
    const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([])
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    const handleSubmit = (id , todo) => {
        const newTodoList = todoList.concat({ id: id, val: todo })
        return (
            setTodo(''),
            todo.length === 0
                ? <Text/>
                : setTodoList(newTodoList) // if I put the dispatch here it doesn't work either
        )
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.addPhotoCont}>
            <TextInput
                placeholder={props.textInputPlaceholder}
                onChangeText={props => setTodo(props)}
                value={todo}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={() => handleSubmit(Date.now(), todo) && dispatch(todo(todoList))}>
                <Text style={styles.addButton}>Add</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Issue is with your handleSubmit function
you're trying to return something which doesn't make sense,
remove the return and perform the submit logic, you can't return a component from handleSubmit (or any event listener)

Comment: Thank you so if I remove the return it should work?

Comment: yes it should work,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set `todo` twice, once as an import, and the second time as state. When you call dispatch and pass in `todo` it is calling the state version.

You should put the dispatch in the `handleSubmit` function.

Also, looking at the `handleSubmit` function, the return will not work.  You can only return one thing.  You can place the other functions above the return statement.

Edit:
Code sample below:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { todo } from './action/todo'

const ToDo = (props) => {
    const [todoInputValue, setTodoInputValue] = useState('')
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    const handleSubmit = (todo) => {
        dispatch(todo({id: Date.now(), val: todoInputValue}))
        setTodoInputValue('')
    }
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.addPhotoCont}>
            <TextInput
                placeholder={props.textInputPlaceholder}
                onChangeText={value => setTodoInputValue(value)}
                value={todoInputValue}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={() => handleSubmit(Date.now())}>
                <Text style={styles.addButton}>Add</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank but where should I put the dispatch because if I put it in the handleSubmit function it will only dispatch  every second submit . So if I type grocery shopping and press submit and then type remind me for example. I’ll only see grocery shopping in the store so please help me with the best place to put the dispatch

Comment: you should put it in the handle submit.